# Как правильно заполнять БД по файлам .sql?

Tags: mysql, база-данных

Что есть:

1. Есть БД с пустыми таблицами.
2. Есть файлы .sql
   Внутри sql-файлов прописано создание таблиц и заполнение, соответственно, если запускать на выполнение эти файлы в **Adminer** на кнопке "Импорт", то будет ошибка создания таблиц, т.к. там в первых строках идет команда создания таблиц.

Получается, чтобы импортировать данные в таблицу, то надо дропнуть все таблицы в БД и запустить sql-файлы?

Или я не в правильном направлении мыслю? (Вариант со стиранием строчки создания таблиц, и запуска, думаю что так неправильно)

Comment: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS

Comment: *Вариант со стиранием строчки создания таблиц, и запуска, думаю что так неправильно* Да, надо не удалять, а корректировать код создания таблиц, как правильно указывает @ВикторКарев. А лучше - озаботиться этим ещё на этапе создания дампа, а не скакать при его разворачивании.

Comment: Ну через PHPMyAdmin - там я просто раньше экспортировал 1 дамп БД и его потом в БД импортировал. Беды не было, а в DataGrip не смог найти такой функции и там только экспорт таблиц с функцией UPDATE или INSERT (можно конечно, поставить галочку "Не создавать таблицы"), поэтому в DataGrid экспортируются таблицы отдельно в каждый файл, с которыми у меня сейчас проблема...